# Looping and incrementing by 12?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am writing a program to figure out the monthly loan payment for **24, 36, 48 and 60 months.**

I would like to know if **I should call the functions inside the loop or outside, and then put my output in the loop?**

I guess the functions should go in the loop because I'm calling the **function 4 times, and that way it loops through each one?** Or, would it just loop through each function 4 times?

I also want the loop to start at 24 and increment by 12 each time until it goes to 60. So I gave that a shot in the `for` loop code, but I'm not sure.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chapter 6 Assignment 2</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    body{
    background-color: grey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
vehiclePrice = +prompt("What is the vehicle price? ","");
moneyDown = +prompt("How much are you putting down? ","");
interestRate = +prompt("What is the interest rate for your loan?  ","");

numMonths;
loanAmount = vehiclePrice - moneyDown;
MonthlyRate = interestRate / 1200;

function monthly_due(interestRate, numMonths, loanAmount){ 
    var base = Math.pow(1 + interestRate, numMonths);
    var payment = loanAmount * interestRate / (1 - (1/base));
    return payment
}

//make function calls here? Function needs to be called 4 times for example
//monthly_due(interestRate, 24, loanAmount);
//monthly_due(interestRate, 36, loanAmount);
//monthly_due(interestRate, 48, loanAmount);
//monthly_due(interestRate, 60, loanAmount);

for (var count = 24; count <= 60; count += 12){
    document.write("Number of months: "); 
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(count); // to display 24, and 12 each time it loops?
    document.write("<br>");
    doucment.write("Monthly Payment: ");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(monthly_due(interestRate, 24, loanAmount); //make function call here?
}
```

Comment: all your variables should be declared with `var`, `let` or `const`. in your call to monthly_due in the last line, you always pass 24 months, not the count

Comment: There are a number of bad [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) in your code; the aforementioned lack of declaring most of your variables, using the `type` attribute on your script tag and using `document.write`. You might benefit from reading this article I wrote about [spotting bad JavaScript tutorials](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/).

Comment: Also, using the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28%29) to convert the answer from the prompts is fine, but you might want to test the value returned from the prompt before converting it, if the user presses the cancel button it will return `null`. `+null` will coerce to `0`, so instead of knowing that they cancelled, you will just go ahead doing the calculation with zeros. That said, in a production ready version you would want to use `input` boxes and check that they are filled out instead of prompts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like so:

Set up an array containing the months when to call the function.
**The benefit with this approach is**, if you need to call it at any other "time" (month) you can just add the value to the array and voilà:

```js
var months = [24, 36, 48, 60];
months.forEach(function (month) {
  console.log(month);
  // call function with parameters
});
```

> I suppose I want to know that would I call the functions inside the
>   loop our outside, And then put my output in the loop ?

So with above solution, you need to call the function inside the loop. But you only need to change the array of `months` if you need to call the function also for another given time.

> I guess the functions should go in the loop because im calling the
>   function 4 times, and that way it loops through each one? Or would it
>   just loop through each function 4 times?

It will call the function for given times it has a value in the array of `months`

Comment: Excellent answer. Doing it this way is great for keeping the code maintainable. You can add any arbitrary amount of months you might have need for in the future instead of having to stick to a particular interval or massively refactoring it to support arbitrary months.